# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication 1.1.1 on ASP.NET Core app

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-authentication

I started a fresh new ASP.NET Core project targeting .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017 -- final version.

I installed a bunch of NuGet packages for authentication. What does the yellow warning mean? Looks like I only have it for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OAuth`. The Facebook and Google packages seem OK. Any idea what the issue is?

[image]

UPDATE: Closing VS 2017 and reopening it seems to have fixed the issue. I'm seeing quite a few issues like that with VS 2017 where closing and reopening it seems to make problems go away. Am I the only one having this issue? Any suggestions on how to get VS 2017 to behave correctly?

Comment: Have you tried restoring nuget packages on the solution? If that doesn't help, does build fail? With what error?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. As I mentioned in the "UPDATE" in original post, closing and reopening VS 2017 fixed the issue.